# NSUrlSession: is it possible to upload files in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

Using `NSUrlSession` with a background configuration let's me download files even if the app gets terminated by iOS. Being curious, I tried to add an upload task and noticed that it won't continue, even not if the app is only suspended.

Apple talks about "[Downloading in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5)" but they don't explicitly state that *uploading* would not be possible.

Can somebody confirm that uploads and background session configuration don't work together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They DO work together.

What you need to do is the following:

Have a NSURLSessionConfiguration with background configuration

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *conf = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"backgroundSession"];
```

Setup a NSURLSession (@property NSURLSession *urlSession)

Obtain the path to the file (fullPath)

Create the NSURLRequest (request)

Create a NSURLSessionTask

```
NSURLSessionTask*task = [self.urlSession uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fullPath];
[task resume];
```

And the task will run in background. You can get the status from NSURLSession delegate methods.

Cheers

Comment: Yeah, that's what I do and it works great on the Simulator but not on the device. iOS8 Simulator does not suspend threads if an app gets backgrounded. If you have a working example, please let me know.

Comment: Have you enabled background modes in your application?

Comment: What specific background mode would you like me to enable? There isn't one for background transfer. And as stated: downloads work fine, upload's don't.

Comment: You were actually right. It does work in the background but it is very, very flaky and undocumented. By the way: it is *not* necessary to enable any background modes.

Comment: @Krumelur Did you figure out how to manage the uploads in the backgrounds? the documentation is still weak.